# Exception when trying to use tensorflow classify android example on a model trained from scratch

Tags: android, tensorflow

I trained an `inception_v3` model using `slim` from scratch, created frozen model, added it to tensorflow android example and I get the following exception:

```
E/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Failed to run TensorFlow inference with inputs:[input], outputs:[InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1]
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
    Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 14648
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tried to explicitly squeeze dimension 1 but dimension was not 1: 0
    [[Node: InceptionV3/Logits/SpatialSqueeze = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[1, 2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](InceptionV3/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/BiasAdd)]]
    at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:295)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runAndFetchMetadata(Session.java:257)
    at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:134)
    at org.tensorflow.demo.TensorFlowImageClassifier.recognizeImage(TensorFlowImageClassifier.java:150)
    at org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity$2.run(ClassifierActivity.java:228)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

**Edit**: By the way I ran `evaluation` and `bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image` and both worked on the trained model on `macOS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was `INPUT_SIZE`. Because the default image size on `inception_v3` is `299x299`:

```
  The default image size used to train this network is 299x299.
```

But the input size in android example is `224`:

```
  private static final int INPUT_SIZE = 224;
```

Changing it to 299 fixed the problem.

Comment: Are there any other solutions to this, or any explanation of why the differing size gives that specific error? Because I'm getting the same error with a pre-built Inceptionv3 model (no retraining) even when I pass 299x299 images.

Comment: @IBBoard You should use the size used when training, so it should have been trained with another image size.

Comment: Thanks - turns out that does solve it. Apparently the module I was using that invoked TensorFlow was doing its own scaling, so my 299x299 image wasn't staying at 299x299. Unfortunately, a) nothing made this clear and b) nothing said what the parameters should be. Accessible documentation is somewhat minimal. I'm now successfully passing things through the classifier, but it fixates on a single class. That's a separate issue, though.

Comment: I am taking images from mobile Gallery, and then calling recognizeImage method of Classifier with InputSize from 224 to 1024, and in all this values its throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception. So resolve this exception, I passes InputSize as 1600 and more, and then I am getting exception as "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tried to explicitly squeeze dimension 1 but dimension was not 1: 22 [[Node: MobilenetV1/Logits/SpatialSqueeze = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[1, 2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/BiasAdd)]]" any idea of this error?

Comment: @sumeet As noted, I think the `INPUT_SIZE` is fixed and set by the trained model, and you have to use the same size when using the classifier.

Comment: I am trying to retrain the model with flag IMAGE_SIZE=2048 and ARCHITECTURE="mobilenet_0.50_${IMAGE_SIZE}", but its throwing error like:-   tensorflow:The Mobilenet input size should be '224', '192', '160', or '128',
 but found '2048' for architecture 'mobilenet_0.50_2048'
ERROR:tensorflow:Did not recognize architecture flag

Comment: @sumeet The error is quite descriptive; you can't use the model with images of size `2048`.

Comment: Yeah that I understood, but question is how to train model with such high ImageSize... Not sure if any other Architecture will work with this

Comment: I didn't found any way to train model with high ImageSize, may be tensor flow is not providing any architecture as of now for this thing...so for the time being I have resolved my issue by resizing image size, which is coming from mobile gallery....Thanks..